# LyX: Paragraphs ignored in PDF output

Tags: lyx, indentation, paragraphs, dirtree

I have a document with `article` class. Here's the minimal example:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{dirtree}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
\end_modules
\begin_local_layout
Float
        Type                  listing
        GuiName               Listing
        Placement             tbp
        Extension             lol
        NumberWithin          none
        Style                 ruled
        ListName              "List of Listings"
        IsPredefined          false
        UsesFloatPkg          true
        RefPrefix             lst
End
\end_local_layout

\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Section
Good Lorem ipsum
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 In venenatis varius mauris in ullamcorper.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Integer eget lectus in nisi aliquet euismod.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
A dirtree (the cause)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
dirtree{%
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

.1 Lorem ipsum.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Bad Lorem ipsum
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Aliquam vitae mauris erat, in vehicula est.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Pellentesque ut justo quis lorem egestas consectetur non non felis.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 Curabitur a odio eget enim feugiat congue.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

When I export the document to PDF (I'm using XeTeX and Freetype Fonts, btw) paragraphs are not indented or otherwise separated in PDF output, although in LyX everything shows as it should (all paragraphs indented except the first in a section). I tried switching from indentation to vertical space but to no avail - LyX shows everything correctly, but output PDF is unchanged. It's worth mentioning I don't use anything fancy as paragraphs, just plain Standard.

Apparently the problem goes away if I remove the dirtree ERT, but I really need it (or some alternative - please suggest).

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Version info:

```
❯❯ xetex -version
XeTeX using libpoppler 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/TeX Live for opensuse.org)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
...
❯❯ zypper if lyx|grep Version
Version: 2.0.5.1-2.1.2
❯❯ zypper if texlive-dirtree|grep Version
Version: 2012.63.0.0.2svn19882-61.1
```

Comment: the document fragment you show has no code relating to paragraph layout. You need to give us at least some clues. Preferably a _complete_ small document starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}` that shows non-indented paragraphs.

Comment: Please post both a .tex and .lyx minimal example. See here for details: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, scottkosty,
I did reduce my file to a minimal example and edited the post. While doing that I also became aware of the apparent cause of the problem - a dirtree ERT, - solution still needed, though.
I'm very new to LyX and (La)TeX, so please suggest further improvements to the post, if needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! - For me, there are indented paragraphs (similar to the LyX presentation) when using XeTeX. What version of XeTeX and package "dirtree" do you use? (on a shell you might check this with `xetex -version` and, for TeXLive, `tlmgr info dirtree`) I have XeTeX 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 and "dirtree" 0.32.

Comment: @e-birk, I've added versions. I don't have tlmgr and `❯❯ cnf tlmgr` shows nothing, so I used `zypper info` to get the versions.

Comment: @Czar Thx. Yes, please write your own answer. This will help others who might have the same problem. (Maybe I will add another approach when I have time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using scientific poking method I've found a workaround - if I wrap dirtree into a framebox:

```
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}%
_dirtree is here_
\end{minipage}}
```

paragraphs work again.